# A characterization for a topological property

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact non-Hausdorff topological space. I am looking for a characterization for the following property on $X$:

**Property:** For each non-empty closed subset $C$ of $X$ there  exists  a partition $C=C_1\bigsqcup\cdots\bigsqcup C_n$ of $C$ into closed subsets $C_i$ of $X$ and there exists a non-empty open set $U_C$ such that for each $i$, $U_C\cap C_i$ is contained in a connected component of $C_i$.

Comment: $U_C$ should be nonempty, right?

Comment: Yes, $U_C$ should be non-empty. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Perhaps some motivation for this question would be helpful? I cannot quite see what this property is about..

Comment: For compact Hausdorff spaces this property is equivalent to the scatteredness (= each non-empty closed subspace has an isolated point). For compact (not necessarily Hausdorff) spaces, the scatteredness implies the property in OP. An example of compact non-Hausdorff non-scattered space with the property is the real line endowed with the cofinite topology.